# SQL Server 2005 install stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm trying to install the stored procedure [WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com), but have no clue where to put it.

I thought it was supposed to go in the Bin folder but I believe it's only for DLLs. How do you install a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005?

I would like to call it using

```
Exec dbo.sp_WhoIsActive
```

since it has some parameters that I can use with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you install a SP in SQL 2005?

You usually execute it within the query window.

That would invovle opening the stored procedure file (.sql) or copy / pasting it in, then pressing execute (or F5).

You might want to take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38682/Overview-of-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure), and [scripting stored procedures](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2006/09/20/12374.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the references, running it put it where it needed to be